# Find specific distribution without affine relation to get $E[f(x)N(x)]=E[f(x)^2]$?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, statistics, random-variables

In $E[f(x)N(x)]=E[f(x)^2]$, $E$ is the expectation on random variable $x$. $N(x)$ is the Gaussian distribution with zero mean, and the affine relation $N(x)=a(x)f(x)+b(x)$ is not allowed.

I just can not find specific distribution for $f(x)$.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: @narip your solution seems to be incorrect